# How to compare dataframes from two different months on a single key

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Pretty new to Python, but as an SEO I'm looking at the benefits of using notebooks in my workflow.

I've got two excel files which I've cleaned and imported into a new notebook using pandas.

I'm trying to compare position changes and create a new data frame with new columns to show previous, new, and changes in positions.

Have a look at the data below:

[image: Df1]

[image: Df2]

Comment: Hey Stuart, are you able to post your data as text so we can test solutions?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Stu, I hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

dataLasMonth = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Rank': [1,2,3,4]
        }

dfLasMonth = pd.DataFrame(dataLasMonth, columns = ['Brand', 'Rank'])

#print (dfLasMonth)

dataThisMonth = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Rank': [3,1,5,10]
        }

dfThisMonth = pd.DataFrame(dataThisMonth, columns = ['Brand', 'Rank'])

#print (dfThisMonth)

dfMerged = dfLasMonth.merge(dfThisMonth,on='Brand' )
dfMerged['diff'] = dfMerged['Rank_x'] - dfMerged['Rank_y']
dfMerged
```